# Wordpress action starting before it's done

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm trying to create a new bbPress forum when new post is saved...I made out this code but the only thing i get it's an infinite loop. The strange is that the loop starts not when i save a post, but first, when i go in "All posts" or in "new Posts". What's the problem please?

This is the code

```
<?php

add_action('save_post', 'register_ForumCustom');

function register_ForumCustom($post_id){

    $post = get_post($post_id);
    // Create post object
    $my_new_post = array(
      'post_title'    => 'Forum di'.$post->post_title,
      'post_content'  => '',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type' => 'forum'
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    $new_forum_id = wp_insert_post( $my_new_post );

    //OK, maybe is here that the loop starts, but i know that the problem is because there is another "save_post". I can solve this, but i don't understand the other problem!

    update_post_meta($post_id, "forum_id", $new_forum_id);

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created the infinite loop with your action.

You have to unhook your action and re-hook it when you are done:

```
// unhook
remove_action('save_post', 'register_ForumCustom');

// do updates/inserts

// re-hook
add_action('save_post', 'register_ForumCustom');
```

see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#Avoiding_infinite_loops